# Touch event on wp7 silverlight. I need to get touched pixel on the photo.

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I get touched pixel's coordinate on wp7? I mean, I have a photo and I want to happen an event, after touching, that uses this touched pixel. How can be solved this problem. I'm working on silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the [GestureService](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-GestureService-in-depth--key-concepts-and-API) in the Silverlight toolkit. There should be a method for getting location of the gesture in there.

Comment: Can't i realize it through simple Image ui control's event? for instance, tap?

Comment: Tap and Click are different events, I have a feeling you want to use gestures. There might be an easier way, but when working with taps, swipes, tap taps. GentureService is usually recommended.